# Java Long Perfomance on 64-bit JVM

Tags: java

I'm interested what is the performance of many Long variables when they are used on 4-bit JVM deployed on x86-64 server? Is there any big difference if I use the same Integers on the same server?

Comment: [Which JVM?](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Java_virtual_machines)

Comment: Recently I did some microbenchmarks with ints and longs on 64-bit Java 7 HotSpot and longs were twice slower. No idea why.

Comment: Java `long` primitives types are 64-bit whilst `int` is 32-bit, twice the size thus more memory bus overhead.  It all depends upon the type of benchmark:  is it focusing on just calculation or memory access?

Comment: @Steve-o Pure calculation, all can be bound to registers or at least L1 cache. Let me post the exact Google Caliper benchmark, see for yourself and compare.

Comment: @Steve-o when using 64-bit processors and buses there should be no difference between long and int calculations, because effectively *all* operations are 64-bit

Comment: @Bohemian But there would be a difference if you processed a million-element array.

Comment: I'm curious: what is the likelihood that one might observe an impact from using longs in stead of ints if the app is **NOT** performing intense operations on million-element arrays?

Comment: @jahroy Take encryption as an example.

Answer (score 1):

My environment:

```
$ java -version
java version "1.7.0_07"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_07-b10)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 23.3-b01, mixed mode)
```

This is the code I ran just now:

```
import com.google.caliper.Runner;
import com.google.caliper.SimpleBenchmark;

public class Performance extends SimpleBenchmark {
  static final Random rnd = new Random();
  static long iters = 100_000_000 + rnd.nextInt(10_000_000);

  public long timeLong(int reps) {
    long sum = rnd.nextLong();
    for (int rep = 0; rep < reps; rep++)
      for (long l = 0; l < iters; l++) sum ^= l;
    return sum;
  }
  public int timeInt(int reps) {
    int sum = rnd.nextInt();
    int iters = (int) Performance.iters;
    for (int rep = 0; rep < reps; rep++)
      for (int l = 0; l < iters; l++) sum ^= l;
    return sum;
  }

  public static void main(String... args) {
    Runner.main(Performance.class, args);
  }
}
```

And these are the results;

```
 0% Scenario{vm=java, trial=0, benchmark=Long} 105721736.11 ns; σ=1752926.46 ns @ 10 trials
50% Scenario{vm=java, trial=0, benchmark=Int} 71749350.00 ns; σ=188518.06 ns @ 3 trials

benchmark    ms linear runtime
     Long 105.7 ==============================
      Int  71.7 ====================
```

If you replace `^=` with `+=`, the difference is even wider:

```
benchmark    ms linear runtime
     Long 109.1 ==============================
      Int  53.8 ==============
```

This may mean that XOR itself is equally fast, but ADD is twice slower.

Comment: I would like to test the code too. Is this the complete code?

Comment: Yes, it is. Just clone Caliper's git repo and include as a dependency: `git clone https://code.google.com/p/caliper/` (you do need Maven as well).

Comment: There are no executable files. I run this from Eclipse and include caliper as a dependent project.